# Schedule a task after system get restarted automatically in Windows task scheduler

Tags: virtual-machine, console-application, windows-task-scheduler

I want to schedule a simple task to send a mail in console application. I want to send an email after system restarted automatically or manually. I am using windows task scheduler with "on Startup" event. but its not started when system restart. Is there any way to run a task after system gets restarted?

Answer (score 0):

When Selecting the "At logon" event for this scenario. Now mail came once system gets restarted automatically or manually. 
You can trigger the task using "At login" event in task scheduler.